# Display larger ruler on android scroll view

Tags: android, image-processing, android-scrollview

I do have long ruler image (shown below) that I need to use as scrollable view on android device.

Can some one please advice for the best way to do the same?

I tried this in two ways,

Initially I tried to put image as background to scroll view but that didn't work as image is too long/large.

Currently I am trying to use BitMap class to crop my image and use the part what I want to display. But again an issue is on every scroll need to crop another part of image and display the same such a way that it will not reflect on screen.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgScaleFirst);
    Options opts = new Options();
    opts.inDither = true;
    opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8;
    opts.inScaled = false; /* Flag for no scalling */ 


    /* Load the bitmap with the options */      
    //Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.lbs_ruler_vert_left,opts);


    Bitmap bmap= BitmapHelper.decodeFile(getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.lbs_ruler_vert_left),182, 4096, true);
    image.setImageBitmap(bmap);
```

I appreciate your input/idea for same.

[image]

Comment: Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: I am updating my question with my current code.

Comment: @AleksG Please see updates

Comment: Read about [`ScrollView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Answer (score 2):

Please check
https://dhingrakimmi.wordpress.com/2015/09/17/android-measurment-scale-my-scale/?preview_id=2
This will show scale without any limit.

Comment: i used this code and code showing ruler but its scroll and ontouch listener not working.In ontouch method there is some typo mistake in your pasted code plz help me if you can

Answer (score 0):

I found this link while searching for a similar requirement to draw a ruler. Hope this helps someone in future.

https://code.google.com/p/ruler-android/source/browse

The idea here is to create a custom view and use canvas to draw lines at appropriate intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Check this that I found, it implements a transparent window and inside it animates a ruler by draagging with touch.
Note: the ruler is not an image, it is drawn in a Canvas, but you can configure the limits, for example 0 to 500.

https://github.com/MiHomes/RuleView

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).